# Knife project only cuts visible surfaces. How to cut opposite sides?

Tags: modeling

I'm using Knife Project, but it's only cutting faces that are visible. I've toggled "limit selection to visible" but that doesn't have any effect. Is there any way for Knife Project to cut interior/invisible surfaces, as well as visible surfaces? Tks!

Answer (score 4):

The option is available in the Operator box, bottom left in 2.8, on the bottom of the *Tools* panel in the previous versions.

[image]

Comment: Oops .. I thought so, too. Deleted.